# Запускаю main.exe выдает ошибку, как исправить?

Tags: python, auto-py-to-exe

[image: Запускаю main.exe выдает такую ошибку, exe был сделан pyintaller'ом.]

Запускаю main.exe выдает такую ошибку, exe был сделан pyintaller'ом.
Код полностью работает и выполняет функционал когда запускается через консоль main.py.

Хочу узнать из за чего ошибка, и как её исправить ведь код полностью работает, писал код в pycharm и Vs code, Vs code делал как будет отображаться программа и есть некий функционал который получаю с pycharm. Pycharm использовал eel для того чтоб передать в js результат функции, все получилось единственно eel установил напрямую в Pycharm, потому что он не видел когда я устанавливал через консоль.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Хочу узнать из за чего ошибка, и как её исправить ведь код полностью работает, писал код в pycharm и Vs code, Vs code делал как будет отображаться программа и есть некий функционал который получаю с pycharm. Pycharm использовал eel для того чтоб передать в js результат функции, все получилось единственно eel установил напрямую в Pycharm, потому что он не видел когда я устанавливал через консоль.

Comment: Как вариант, посоветую переписать на другой язык программирования который компилируется в .exe напрямую)

Comment: Не очень хотелось, например какой язык?

Comment: C, C++ или Rust